# Listen to on(child_added) in multiple components - React native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to build an instant messaging application using React Native with firebase. The problem is querying newly received messages, it works well when the user has opened the chat screen( using `on('child_added').limitToLast(1)` to avoid multiple unnecessary calls). But, if the user navigates away from the chat and subsequently receives multiple messages, all the received messages aren't added to the chat log as the chat component runs for the latest child added only. How do I make sure that the application listens to all the `child_added` irrespective of what screen the user is in ? I don't think implementing `on('child_added')` in every component is a good idea, as it might instead create multiple copies of the same message, if the user navigates between the chat and the other screen just when the message is received.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options either you attach listeners using a loop, I mean that create a loop and one by one attach a listener to all required nodes. But I think no one will prefer it.

So the second way is that you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging and Send message from the sender side and in onMessgeReceived in the receiver application you can retrieve the data whatever you have passed from the sender side. This will also help you get updates like notifications even if the application is not running.

Comment: Could you please attach any links that take us through the process? As far as I know, FCM is used to compose and send push notifications, I'm not sure how to tie up the complete message data, also if you could put up a snippet to show the implementation of `onMessageReceived`  and where to implement it(Within the chat component or Inbox component or anywhere else ), it'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: you will get the updates like the new messages through FCM and append it to the list of chat which is available already and if not then you need to fetch older chats, may you have noticed this in whatsapp that they load older chats even you open the chat screen and just show to latest 1-2 messages. So use the same message model in FCM and retreive it on the receiver and furter append it to chat list. Though I'm not a React Native developer so I can just guide you through the concepts.

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it and get back shortly!

Comment: Okay @PrajwalKulkarni, waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In React apps, I typically either [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a high-level component that both screens share.

But in other frameworks, I sometimes create a separate "class" to manage the listeners in scenarios such as this. You then access this class from each component that needs access to the data, and it can manage the listeners and the data from those listeners.

React has a lot of frameworks for such stat management too, so you might want to consider looking into https://redux.js.org/ or [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+state+management).

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Using an application-wide state management system like redux or context API, is a good idea, as you suggested. But as far as I know, states could be updated only when an action is dispatched, and usually, actions are dispatched from components that trigger state updates. But, in this case, the situation is quite the opposite, more like a callback triggered from firebase when a new document is added(in this scenario, sending/receiving of a new message). Could you care to explain with a code snippet or link up any resource that'd help me set up a listener class?